# Trouble fitting a function with scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-analysis, curve-fitting

I am currently trying to evaluate some data of mine and tried replicating the fit function described here: https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_classic_dr_variable.htm

At first I was having some trouble with `numpy.float_power` overflowing, but I think I fixed it (did I really?).

I am now using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to fit the described sigmoid to my data, but it never actually seems to fit, but instead produces constant functions and I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''
Just a method that produces some simple test data
'''
def test_data_1():
    return np.array([[0.000610352, 0.002441406, 0.009765625, 0.0390625, 0.15625, 0.625, 2.5, 10],
                    [0.89, 0.81, 0.64, 0.48, 0.45, 0.50, 0.58, 0.70]])

'''
Just a simple method that produces some more test data
'''
def test_data_2():
    return np.array([[0.000610352, 0.002441406, 0.009765625, 0.0390625, 0.15625, 0.625, 2.5, 10],
                     [1, 0.83, 0.68, 0.52, 0.48, 0.59, 0.75, 0.62]])

'''
Dose response curve as described in: https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_classic_dr_variable.htm
'''
def sigmoidal_dose_response_with_variable_slope(x_data, *params):
    # Extract relevant parameters. Flattening the array just in case?
    r_params = np.array(params).flatten()
    bottom = r_params[0]
    top = r_params[1]
    logec50 = r_params[2]
    slope = r_params[3]

    # Calculating the numerator
    numerator = top - bottom
    # Calculating the denominator
    denominator = 1 + np.float_power(10, (logec50 - x_data) * slope, dtype=np.longdouble)
    return np.array(bottom + (numerator / denominator), dtype=np.float64)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x_data, y_data = test_data_1()

    # Guessing bottom and top as the highest and lowest y-values.
    bottom_guess = np.min(y_data)
    bottom_guess_idx = np.argmin(y_data)
    top_guess = np.max(y_data)
    top_guess_idx = np.argmax(y_data)

    # Guessing logec50 as the middle between those parameters
    logec50_guess = np.linalg.norm(x_data[top_guess_idx] - x_data[bottom_guess_idx]) / 2 \
                    + np.min([x_data[top_guess_idx], x_data[bottom_guess_idx]])

    # Guessing a slope of 1
    slope_guess = 1
    p0 = [bottom_guess, top_guess, logec50_guess, slope_guess]

    # Fitting the curve to my data
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoidal_dose_response_with_variable_slope, x_data, y_data, p0)

    # Making the x-axis scale logarithmically
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xscale('log')

    # Plot my data
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 's')

    # Calculate function data. The borders are merely a guess
    x_val = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    y_val = sigmoidal_dose_response_with_variable_slope(x_val, popt)

    # Plot
    plt.plot(x_val, y_val)
    plt.show()
```

It should be easily testable.

Update:
Something like this is what I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: Your data does not looks like a sigmoid function at all. A sigmoid function will be a very bad model in your case. (it is also why your curve is almost flat, `curve_fit` try to find some good parameter but since it is not possible `1+10^(logec50-x)*sloope` tend to `+inf` and your equation become `bottom + numerator/inf = bottom` a constant value)

Comment: That is kinda true. However it would be fine, if it'd only fit to the first turn of the curve (so a boundary value, values after that could be discarded). However I have no idea ho.w to ifnd one such value. Any ideas? This is probably a bigger problem than I'd imagined

Comment: @LennyEing. You can find the portion of the data that is monotonic. Are you looking for the left or right part of the curve?

Comment: Why are you trying to fit a sigmoid to non-sigmoid data?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The data might not be monotonic as cleary in reality as it is in this case.
Because I need to fit it to sigmoid dose response, because that is the standard method used in the field that this is needed for. As i said in another comment before, I am however able to discard some of the data after a vertain point, I don't know how to find that point though.

Comment: @LennyEing. It would be helpful to show a plot in your question in that case, to demonstrate what you want. It may be useful to get rid of the log scaling for that part too.

Comment: Yep does not look sigmoid but does look polynomial, have a look at [polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).